# wiki for sphinx+ReStructuredText server

Tags: wiki, restructuredtext, sphinx

I've been using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) as a document engine for an internal document server in my company. It uses [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) as its markup language.

Today, I need to edit the source files manually, compile the HTML, check that it works and then upload it to an internal server. This is tedious and my colleagues are refrained from updating the documents.

Wiki would be a great solution, but Is there a free, open-source wiki engine that supports reStructuredText, or at least plain text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) supports reStructuredText.  By default, it's as easy as:

```
{{{
#!rst
.. note:: I use reStructuredText all the time...
}}}
```

and you should also be able configure it to be the default (but I don't remember if that requires any hacking or not)...

There's a high-powered wiki in Haskell called [Gitit](https://github.com/jgm/gitit) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider [`sphinx-autobuild`](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autobuild/). It watches for file changes in a particular directory (i.e., Sphinx source directory) and automatically re-builds the Sphinx documents when changes are detected. Might not be the ideal solution, but enough to mitigate some of the problems you mentioned.